# Registry - Finding a user's installation registry hive

Tags: registry

What I'm trying to do right now is find a way to go to the user's installation hive where the programs are registered.

I have found several topic suggesting to go to somewhere like:

```
HKEY_USERS\S-15-21-something-something-something-4digit_Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache
```

But I noticed that, let's say, I have two computers, with only one user in each.
I compared their registry hives in said location to be completely different.

Is there a way to find this without me creating separate files for every number I could think of?

Comment: That `S-15-21-something` is called a SID. I'm puzzled whose user's sid you are looking for? The currently logged in user? (Then you can just look in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` instead of `HKEY_USERS\<sid>_Classes`). Some other user you know the name of? Or the user who is interactively logged on? Or the user who created a specific file?  also note that registry hives under HKEY_USERS\ are only mounted if the user logged on at least once since reboot. Otherwise you'd have to mount it first.

Comment: Because some of my games need to be installed, and I dont want to again, I'm trying to put the keys in the directory. The currently logged in user.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not know what you want to achieve. The MUICache is used to cache names of applications, and you can find it for the current user at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\MuiCache` (you can compare, it has the the same content as the key you posted above).

Also, I am pretty sure that "installing" a game does a lot more than just change some registry keys (put some files into WinSXS, into the user profile, and do some changes in the registry at various spots).

So sorry. Perhaps someone else understands what you want and can help you.